# Jenkins sometime fails to auto-promote job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, promotions

I have really big net of jobs. Something Like this:
Start job: A, job to promote: Z, Requires: E, F, G

```
 A-------
|  \     |
B  C     D
|   |   / \
E   F  G   H 
|   |  |   |
I   J  K   L
============ > if(E,F,G) then Promote Z
```

The question is: why it sometimes work? And sometimes( it seems on bigger jenkins load) I have to manually promote Z?

Answer (score 1):

Are you giving it enough time to execute? Promotions take up an executor to run. If your server is under load, and there are no available executors, it will queue up the promotion. However the promotion star appears immediately at the time of triggering (auto or not) of the promotion.

Comment: There isn't set any timeout for promotion to occur.

Comment: I am not saying there is a timeout configuration. I am asking if you have free executors available to execute the promotion

Comment: Even if there are no at the moment. Promotion is queued and executed later. Ofcourse: if it is lanuched at all...